# IONIC inappbrowser loadstop event not working in IOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am launching an https://... URL in iPhone within inAppBrowser. I am trying to call 'loadstop' event for inappbrowser. It is not getting called in Iphone but it works for Android. 
Please let me know if there is any API update is required.

Thanks,

Comment: 'Loadstop' event is not getting called for inAppBrowser for ios. Please let me know the way to launch inAppBrowser in ios.

Comment: check my answer to following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955807/cordova-in-app-browser-event-not-firing-ios/57050650#57050650